# Setup LDAPS authentification in Zabbix

Tags: php, debian, ldap, zabbix

I try to setup LDAPS authentification on Zabbix 2.4 but it's not working. Here is the infos on my configuration :

- OS : Debian
- PHP packages installed :

  `libapache2-mod-php5 php-pear
  php5
  php5-cli
  php5-common
  php5-curl
  php5-gd
  php5-imagick
  php5-json
  php5-ldap
  php5-mysqlnd
  php5-pgsql
  php5-readline
  php5-sasl
  zabbix-frontend-php`
- This command is working :

ldapsearch -H ldaps://ldaps.mptest.be:636 -D cn=reader,dc=antidot,dc=prv -W -b ou=people,dc=antidot,dc=prv

Same URI, OU, login, password in the Authentification LDAP setup page on zabbix, I have this :

ldap_bind(): Unable to bind to server: Can't contact LDAP server

[authentication.php:120 → CLdapAuthValidator->validate() → CLdap->checkPass() → ldap_bind() in /usr/share/zabbix/include/classes/ldap/CLdap.php:112] LDAP: cannot bind by given Bind DN. Login name or password is incorrect!

Here is the content of /etc/ldap/ldap.conf:

`TLS_REQCERT allow
BASE        dc=antidot,dc=prv
URI     ldaps://ldap.mptest.be
TLS_CACERTDIR   /etc/ssl/mptest/wildcard_mptest_be.ca`

(Authentification without SSL, on port 386 is not possible)

Comment: What version of Debian? Have you checked connectivity *without SSL* (be careful with this, change password immediately after if you do)? Tell us also contents of */etc/ldap.conf*.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I edit the main post with the ldap config. unfortunately, Ldap on port 386 without SSL is not possible.

Comment: Everything seems to be fine here. Are there any per-process or per-user firewall rules? Have you tested LDAPS connectivity with another, simple PHP script? And have you considered authenticating in httpd (Apache?) and passing REMOTE_USER to application? Zabbix works that way in my workplace (although with Kerberos, not LDAP, as we prefer having SSO).

Comment: I did try a test PHP :
`code`<?php
$handle = ldap_connect('ldaps://ldaps.mptest.be',636);
$bind = ldap_bind($handle, 'cn=reader,dc=antidot,dc=prv', 'reader');
echo "TEST BIND";
if ($bind) {
    if (ldap_get_option($handle, LDAP_OPT_DIAGNOSTIC_MESSAGE, $extended_error)) {
        echo "Error Binding to LDAP: $extended_error";
    } else {
        echo "Error Binding to LDAP: No additional information is available.";
    }
} else {
        echo "not binding";
}
?>`code`

Comment: And i have a dokuwiki page that is using that LDAPS server but in anoymous

Comment: At the moment, besides configuring httpd authentication as already mentioned, I can only recommend: finding the lines with *ldap_connect()* and *ldap_bind()* in Zabbix panel and modify it temporarily to dump all arguments to be analyzed (look for leading/trailing spaces, NULLs, etc.); sniffing the traffic with *tcpdump*, although with SSL this will be of limited use.

Answer (score 1):

This is what works on Ubuntu 14.04. Debian based system should be the same:

https://www.novell.com/coolsolutions/tip/5838.html

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: The tip in the answer is really good, and I think that this was the site that also helped me getting onto the right track. Good input, thank you @jouflux.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this problem by visiting the Zabbix web interface, then going to *Administration* -> *Authentication* -> *LDAP* and changing the *LDAP host* parameter from hostname (e.g. `ldap.example.com`) to its IP address (e.g., `10.6.10.10`).

Answer (score 0):

PHP's LDAP is, to be frank, pure crap. Some time ago I did also struggle with Zabbix and LDAPS. You can do everything 100% correct, but it will still fail. So, no worries, the issue here is not on your side.

To get that working you have to disable TLS/SSL certificate validation in OpenLDAP. PHP's LDAP uses the OpenLDAP libraries, and therefore `/etc/openldap/ldap.conf` or `~/.ldaprc` are loaded and matter. (This can be seen, using an example PHP LDAP query and running that with `strace -e trace=open php example.php`). The problem here seems to be located in the area of PHPs usage of the OpenLDAP libraries, some missing/wrong/not implemented calls for successful TLS certificate validation. Fixing that would involve patching PHP.

`TLS_REQCERT never` should be the parameter needed to get that going. The URL and OU/DC settings in ldap.conf should not be relevant as they are provided from the Zabbix configuration. I strongly suggest to modify that in `~/.ldaprc` of your webservers home directory, to not affect any other application using LDAPS.

This solution is not a good one, but still better than falling back to unencrypted LDAP. And just to clarify, I tried it with manually placing CACerts for OpenLDAP, regenerating the cert cache and setting `TLS_REQCERT` to `always`. This worked fine using e.g. `ldapsearch` (uses the same librarie as PHP), but still failed with PHPs LDAP feature. So this attempt will likely be a waste of time. I did not try to place the client certificate and use `TLS_KEY/TLS_CERT` as indicated in the answer from @jouflux. If that works it would be a better solution.